Unable to use X11 forwarding inside a ROS docker image
I'm using ROS in an ubuntu docker image running on a pi running raspbian, and when I SSH into the pi I can do X11 forwarding and have things pop up on my laptop. But when I open the container (still SSHed in) and try to open things (xclock has been my test) it prints: Error: Can not access display localhost:10.
The display environment variable of localhost:10 works outside of the container, but not inside. any ideas why? I'm using ros:humble-ros-core and then I used apt-get to install xorg, xauth, and openbox, and then i used docker commit to save it. The full command im running is sudo docker run -it --rm --name ros_container -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix custom_ros_img
